# Operator self-adjoint

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have this paragraph :

"Let M be a Hilbert-Riemannian manifold. $f \in C^2(M,R), p \in K$
is called a nondegenerate critical point, if $d^2 f (p)$ has a bounded inverse.
Since $A = d^2 f (p)$ is a self-adjoint operator which possesses a resolution of
identity"

$K$ is the set of critical points.

I don't understand why $A$ is a self-adjoint operator ?

and what it means "posseses a resolution of identity"

[image]

Please

Thank you

Comment: It is referring to the [spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators). However, the language used looks extremely exaggerated to me as $d^2f(p)$ is a finite-dimensional operator, that is, nothing more than a matrix, so to speak. Therefore it seems to me that the author is just saying that $d^2f(p)$, being a symmetric matrix, is diagonalizable.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, this is on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert manifold.

Comment: In finite dimensions it boils down to ${\partial^2 f \over \partial x \partial y} = {\partial^2 f \over \partial y \partial x}$... maybe there's some natural generalization.

Comment: Wht it means : posseses a resolution of identity

Comment: It would be helpful if you include what comes after this fragment. Give it a bit more context.

Comment: i edited my message

Comment: The second derivative of a $C^2$ map between Banach spaces is always symmetric, which is why $d^2 f(p)$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Resolution_of_the_identity

A resolution of the identity is something that self-adjoins operators on Hilbert spaces have; it is a one-paramater family of projections onto us spaces that is strongly connected to the spectral decomposition; the Eigenvalues correspond to jumps in the one-parameter family.

The operator is self adjoint because the space is $C^2$, just like in the finite dimensional case. In fact, given any two entries, you should be able to restrict yourself to a two-dimensional subset intersecting the point of interest, and on this subset the differential operator becomes a two by two matrix.